# Arquivos crt*.o em C

Tags: c, gcc

Para que servem os arquivos `crt1.o,crt0.o,crti.o e crtn.o` em um programa C. Sei que a extensão `.o` tem a ver com arquivo objeto, mas para que os arquivos citados servem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crt*.o` são as [implementações](https://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt) do **C** **R**un**t**ime, o conjunto de funções que dão suporte a funcionalidades básicas do C como os *stubs* que transformam chamadas de função a *system calls* em *traps*, o código que inicializa a pilha e organiza o vetor `argv` antes de passar a execução para `main()`, etc. Eles são necessários nos chamados sistemas [*hosted*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#4.p6), em que o ambiente de tempo de execução deve fornecer alguns serviços mínimos.